# CSS radial counter - add another circle to fill missing part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am generating circular counters for polls where I draw counter for each answer.

I am using this "plugin": http://blakek.us/labs/jquery/css3-pie-graph-timer/

I have this output:

[image: 1]

### Wanted output:

[image: 2]  [image: 4]

### Example:

http://jsbin.com/iHuXInU/1/edit

http://jsfiddle.net/cvJvB/

### My try:

http://jsbin.com/ApUXiTE/1/edit

http://jsfiddle.net/R6j92/

### HTML:

```
  <div class="pollAnswerBar">15</div>
  <br>
  <div class="pollAnswerBar">50</div>
  <br>
  <div class="pollAnswerBar">75</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.pollAnswerBar {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 50px;
    width:1em;
    height:1em;

}
.pollAnswerBar > .percent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.05em;
    left: 0.5em;
    right: 0.5em;
    width: 3.33em;
    font-size: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.pollAnswerBar > #slice {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    clip:rect(0px,1em,1em,0.5em);
}
.pollAnswerBar > #slice.gt50 {
    clip:rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pollAnswerBar > #slice > .pie {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 0.1em;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.8em; /* 1 - (2 * border width) */
    height: 0.8em; /* 1 - (2 * border width) */
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em; 
    border-radius: 0.5em; 
}
.pollAnswerBar > #slice > .pie.fill {
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
    transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
}
```

### JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function drawCounter(percent, element) {
        jQuery(element).html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"' + (percent > 50 ? ' class="gt50"' : '') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
        var deg = 360 * (percent / 100);
        jQuery('#slice .pie', element).css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
        });
        jQuery('.percent', element).html(Math.round(percent) + '%');
    }

    jQuery('.pollAnswerBar').each(function (index, element) {
        var percent = jQuery(element).text();
        console.log(percent);
        drawCounter(percent, element);
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do this kind of thing in CSS when SVG makes it so much easier??

Comment: I need to control border color with CSS, in case of changing theme of page.

Comment: It is possible to use CSS to style SVG images. [See here for more info](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html)

Comment: @Spudley I am considering SVG, thanks for tip :) +1. But what about android 2.2 support ?

Comment: Re Android 2: Yes, that is an issue for SVG. But to be honest, Android 2 usage is similar to IE6/7; very few people use Android 2 devices for browsing. You're actually affecting more people by using CSS/`border-radius` since it isn't supported by IE8, which as much higher usage than Android 2. (note: my own current phone is Android 2 so this affects me directly, but I still wouldn't worry about it; I don't really use the device for browsing as it's too slow, and I'm due for an upgrade soon anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:1` rule to your `.pollAnswerBar > #slice > .pie` selector

i.e

```
.pollAnswerBar > #slice > .pie {

   border-color: red;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.1em;
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    height: 0.8em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.8em;
    z-index: 1;

}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/R6j92/1/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin, it's much better: 
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/